# Approved edits and reputation issue

Tags: support, reputation, edits

I have faced an issue mentioned below.

The number of approved edits are getting reduced. I do not understand how that is happening.

My reputation is also getting reduced. However there are no down votes.

Comment: One thing (unrelated to your question in the current form): when suggesting edits please describe better what you are really suggesting -- don't use the same phrase every time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can track your reputation at [this page](https://askubuntu.com/users/770676/eranda-peiris?tab=reputation).  What is shown is that a number of answers and/or questions you've made have recently been deleted either because they or their parent questions were deleted.  As such, the reputation you had gained was taken away, and your reputation tab shows this by "deleted post" or "removed" next to the `-2` entries.

---

As for your rejected edit suggestions, I've taken a look at a lot of your suggestions over the past couple of days.  The ones that were rejected are because your edits to 'improve formatting' didn't add anything to the post and didn't make anything easier to read or understand.

When making edits, you need to make sure the edits are *substantial*.  If you are editing something to add code formatting, and then editing other things that are completely superfluous just to meet the required threshold to suggest the edit, then you should *really* reevaluate what type of edits you're doing.  Minor edits to just improve formatting which don't really make the post easier to read are commonly rejected, and this is reflected by the community reviews of your edit suggestions.

Since your edits are being rejected, you should review *why* they were rejected, and learn from the decline reasons how to improve your edit suggestions or things in which you should avoid with regards to edit suggestions (and where *not* to suggest an edit).

Comment: I checked today Ubuntu reputation, it is reduced by 10.Can help me to find it out what is the matter of that? No down votes at all.

Comment: @ErandaPeiris the same reason as before: a question you had edited was deleted (-2 rep) and also a question you had answered which had one upvote and one downvote (so 8 in total, meaning -8 rep when deleted). That is a sum of -10 rep.

Comment: @ErandaPeiris Whenever you have a question about why your rep goes up or down, ***[always review your reputation at the reputation listing in your profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/770676/eranda-peiris?tab=reputation)***.  It usually gives you these answers yourself, so we don't have to explain every single reputation gain/loss you have.